# tinymce wordpress copy and paste losing http:// prefix

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

when copying and pasting images in tinymce (in wordpress) the url of the image loses its prefix. is there some way to fix this. I am using wordpress mu 2.9.2 and tinymce advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

from: http://nerdee.blogspot.com/2009/02/tinymce-relative-path-img-problem.html

TinyMCE relative path IMG problem
I've been using TinyMCE as a WYSIWYG editor on my website www.puppages.com. I absolutely LOVE it. There was one issue that was a little frustrating. When someone tried to link back to another page on the site (or an image/document on the site), the TinyMCE code would convert the absolute path into a relative path and the relative path would not work. I was able to fix this by doign some javascript editing.

Here's the solution:

1. Open the tiny_mce.js file.
2. Find all references to the function: toRelative(u)
3. replace with return u
4. save

Comment: I don't think this is correct. I have the same problem as the poster, and I tried that solution. It does not work. The toRelative isn't even called when the image is pasted. I think the difference is that @InnateDev and I are pasting an image (so this is the src url) while the link you give is to through the image link button.